# WPF MVVM DataGrid Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Well, not the problem, just working on my course work and trying an MVVM pattern. All is working well or I think so. But this thing shouldn't work and I don't understand why is it okay...

Here is a ViewModel:

```
    public class ViewModel : OnPropertyChangedClass
    {
        private readonly static IService service = new Service();
        private static reFolder selectedFolder;
        private ObservableCollection<reObject> folders;
        public ObservableCollection<reObject> Folders
        {
            get => folders;
            set
            {
                folders = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        private reFolder folderExplorer;
        public reFolder FolderExplorer
        {
            get => folderExplorer;
            set
            {
                folderExplorer = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

//these methods are called from MainWindow.xaml.cs, it's the only way I've found to track nodes
        public static void NodeExpanded()
        {
            service.UpdateFolder(selectedFolder);
            service.ChangeFolderExpandedState(selectedFolder);
        }
        public static void NodeSelected(reFolder folder)
        {
            selectedFolder = folder;
            service.UpdateExplorer(selectedFolder);
        }
        public ViewModel()
        {
            folders = service.UpdateDrives();
            folderExplorer = service.UpdateExplorer(null);
        }
    }
```

And the part in MainWindow.xaml

```
        <DataGrid x:Name="Explorer" ItemsSource="{Binding FolderExplorer.FoldersFiles}" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="{x:Null}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="16" IsReadOnly="True" Width="168" Foreground="#FF1BB37C"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

As I understand, DataGrid updates after calling OnPropertyChanged(), but it's only called once in the constructor:

```
folderExplorer = service.UpdateExplorer(null);
```

But when I just select something in the TreeView in runtime, xaml.cs calles NodeSelected method:

```
service.UpdateExplorer(selectedFolder);
```

It not triggers setter or OnPropertyChanged in debug, but DataGrid still updates.
Can somebody explain me this, please. If you need more code, just tell me, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit difficult to understand. I read it like you wonder about the different behavior of the `DataGrid` compared to the `TreeView`?

Your expectations are correct: the `DataGrid` will update the cell, if the bound property has changed.
But this is never happening in your case - at least this is what I can tell from your posted code. Opposed to your claims, even your posted constructor is not raising the `PropertyChanged` event:

```
// Assignment of a field. Fields never raise PropertyChanged (your code)
folderExplorer = service.UpdateExplorer(null);

// Assignment of a property. Properties can raise PropertyChanged
FolderExplorer = service.UpdateExplorer(null);
```

You didn't posted this code, because you thought it is unimportant. That's why I assume you are expecting the execution of the `FolderExplorer` set method.

But this is not happening for a good reason: the properties that are actually edited and updated are inside the `FolderExplorer.FoldersFiles` collection. Set a breakpoint into the class of the items that are contained in the `FoldersFiles` on the `Name` property and you will see, that the properties set methods are called whenever you edit the corresponding `DataGrid` cell.

If a nested property changes e.g. `FolderExplorer.FoldersFiles/FolderFile.Name`, then `PropertyChanged` is *only* raised on the actual (nested) property and not on all the top level properties along the path of a nested property call.

Furthermore your comparison of the `DataGrid` behavior with the `TreeView` behavior is not valid. Editing a cell modifies the data while selecting doesn't. So clicking on a cell won't raise any `PropertyChanged` events in the first place. In this scenario a property change would only occur, if you bind the `DataGrid.SelectedItem` to a property of your `ViewModel`.